# Using constants in inherited php classes

Tags: php

When you have inherited classes, where the child class sets some constants and the parent class has a static method that needs to use them:

```
class some_helperclass {

    public static function add_them() {

        return self::some_c + self::another_c;
    }

}    

class mainclass extends some_helperclass {

    const some_c  = 1;
    const another_c  = 2;

}
```

I get an error when I try to execute this:

`mainclass::add_them()`

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: "an error" - well, that's not very specific. Wanna tell anyone, or maybe google it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good example of how [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) works.

I won't rewrite the documentation for it, but the TL;DR is that `self` refers to the literal class that executes the code. In your example it's `mainclass` that defines the constants, but `some_helperclass` that reads them so it doesn't work using `self`.

If you change to use `static::CONST_NAME` it [will work](https://eval.in/740194).

Also - it's good practice to name constants in upper case only.

Code example:

```
<?php

class some_helperclass {

public static function add_them() {

    return static::some_c + static::another_c;
    }

}    

class mainclass extends some_helperclass {

    const some_c  = 1;
    const another_c  = 2;

}

var_dump(mainclass::add_them());
```

Output: `int(3)`

Comment: eval.in was throwing (internal) server errors (an error on their end I'm sure). I edited

Comment: Thanks Fred- it does that sometimes :-)

Comment: Great!  Thank you both for your help. :)